# mapstate to dynamic state objects of vuex store from the component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to build a watchlist (data streaming program) by vue3 with vuex.  When a watchlist component subscribes for a symbol it should receive updates for that symbol from the store. When removing the subscription from the component that particular component should not receive that state change after that. We cannot hardcode symbol names in store to mapstate from component for each individually since there can be hundreds. if we take all the symbols as an attribute of a single object and map the state to it it will be a performance overhead since not all watchLists are referring to all the symbols.

So my question is there any way to inject a dynamically changing array to mapstate?

In component->

```
computed: {
    ...mapState([this should change dynamically]),
  },
```

in Store->

```
   state : {
      these states also should be dynamic
  },
```

or is there any workaround in vue to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an alternative way by using getters. When we are using that we don't have to map state at all.

I am returning a function from getters with an argument since Vuex getters don't accept arguments.

```
  symbol: (state) => (symbol) => {
           return state.payload[symbol]
       }
```

and from the component, I am watching for that getter.

```
   this.$store.watch(
          (state, getters) => getters.allSymbols(currency),
          (newValue, oldValue) => {
            this.symbolObjects[symbol] = newValue;
           // do something
          },
      );
```

the watch is triggering every time the currency update. Also using the Vuex watcher gives the benefit of accessing both old and new values.